# Cartier Divisors and Ideal sheaves (Huybrechts Complex Geometry)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm reading *Complex Geometry-an introduction* by *Daniel Huybrechts*. In section 2.3, he gives a group homomorphism $\mathcal{O}: \operatorname{Div}(X)\to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$, and he proves that for any effective divisor $D\in \operatorname{Div}(X)$, there exists a nonzero global section $s$ of $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ such that $Z(s)=D$.

Now let $Y$ be a irreducible hypersurface, then the section $s\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(Y))$ with $Z(s)=Y$ gives rise to a sheaf homomorphism $\mathcal{O}(X)\to \mathcal{O}(Y)$ and dually to $\mathcal{O}(-Y)\to \mathcal{O}_X$. I think that this two homomorphisms are $f\mapsto fs$ and $t^*\mapsto t^*(S)$ locally.

Then he gives Lemma 2.3.22:

**Lemma 2.3.22**  The induced map $\mathcal{O}(-Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is injective and the image is the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of $Y \subset X$ of holomorphic functions vanishing on $Y$.

In the proof, he says that locally the map is given by multiplication with the equation defining $Y$. I can't understand this claim and why it's injective.

Comment: thank you I also trapped by this statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explain the statement "locally the map is given my multiplication". Locally means you reduce to an affine neighbourhood looking like $X=\mathbf{C}^n$. Then $Y$ is defined (locally) by regular holomorphic function $f \in \mathcal{O}_X$. Now $f$ defines a sheaf of ideals $(f)\subset \mathcal{O}_X$. Then the map is $\mathcal{O}(-Y) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$ is just the inclusion $ f\mathcal{O}_X=(f)\hookrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$.

**Edit**. If $D$ is an effective divisor locally given by a regular $f$, its associated line bundle $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ is by definition locally generated by elements of the form $f^{-1}$! So sections of this bundle might have poles! However, the **dual** bundle $\mathcal{O}(-Y)$ is generated by the functions $f$, which have only zeros, no poles, and obviously define the ideal in $\mathcal{O}_X$.
This is essentially explained quite well [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)#Cartier_divisors)
on wikipedia.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand why $\mathcal{O}(-Y)$ is just the ideal sheaf $f\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: I edited and explained, does it make sense now? It takes a while to get used to that...

Comment: Hi @AbstractNonsense , $O(Y)$ is the line bundle associated to the effective (Weil) divisor , the data contains in the Cartier 
 divisor should be holomorphic function . Why it's $1/f$?

Comment: Its true that the Cartier divisor $D$ is defined by $(U_i,f_i)$ with $f_i$ regular. But this statement is a statement of line bundles, and the line bundle assoc. to $D$ is the sub sheaf of $K(X)$ generated by $f_i^{-1}$ (I know that's confusing).

Comment: Note that you can not cover a complex manifold by opens biholomorhic to $\mathbf C^n$. You need to take open balls $B_1(0) \subset \mathbf C^n$. This is because $\mathbf C^n$ is not biholomorphic to $B_1(0)$, as the latter has bounded holomorphic functions, but the former does not (by Liouville's theorem).